# Would Vivek Ramaswamy have the power to release the full Geoffrey Epstein client lists?

Tags: united-states, judiciary, us-president, separation-of-powers

Vivek Tamaswamy in campaigning for President [promises](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Zq2cP-qXrII) that he will release full unredacted client lists of Geoffrey Epstein if elected. But would a President, or for that matter, without legislative supremacy, even the legislature, have the power to do this as the redaction and sealing processes seem to have been the doings of the judiciary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Would Vivek Ramaswamy have the power to release the full Geoffrey
> Epstein client lists?

**No.**

The case was [filed](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/names-jeffrey-epstein-associates-others-unsealed-lawsuit-documents-rcna131621) in the U.S. District Court for the Southern District of New York, a federal trial court in New York City. This is a private civil lawsuit, not one brought by the U.S. Government.

He would not have the authority to directly order that this happen, because the President doesn't have direct authority over the judicial branch and the U.S. government is not a party seeking relief in the case.

He could ask the U.S. Attorney General, and through the U.S. AG, the U.S. Attorney for the Southern District of New York, to seek to intervene in the case, in order to ask the judge in the case to release documents to the fullest extent allowed by law, much like existing media companies have already.

The existing U.S. Attorney has not played any significant role in limiting disclosure of these documents. It isn't clear that U.S. law allows full disclosure to the extent he purports that he will order it. Some information in the case may be legally protected from disclosure.

Comment: Could he introduce or instigate a bill for congress to pass for the disclosure?

Comment: @TylerDurden that bill would be violating multiple constitutional parts: It could be a bill of attainder (by declaring someone specific to not have certain rights), it could be a violation of *nulla poena sine legis*/*ex post facto* law as it is a criminal proceeding: the law can't retroactively remove checks/balances/protections that were in place when the act happened.

Comment: @TylerDurden While I am not as confident as Trish that the law would be unconstitutional, and I'm comfortable that it wouldn't be a bill of attainder, the *ex post facto* law part would be a hurdle and the possible invalidation of the law as applied in parts as an impairment of a contract under the contracts clause of the U.S., Constitution come to mind. It might be possible and details would matter.

Comment: It would have to depend on what sort of bill congress drafts, but it's not going to hinge on the ex post facto aspect (as this is a civil matter). Essentially, I can't see a lane for congress to draft a bill that would not be either redundant and therefore pointless (rebuttable common law presumption of disclosure is still in place, after all) or sail too close to a bill of attainder under the rationale of Nixon v GSA, 433 U.S. 425. Ultimately, we need to see how congress words the statute first, since while almost certainly invalid, how it'd be invalid depends on the wording.